# angular-class starter

Tags: angular2, webpack

Здравствуйте, скачиваю  angular-class starter и хочу удалить из него все компоненты, ну то есть чтобы он остался голым и я мог писать с чистого листа, если удаляю все компоненты, удаляю их в app.module.ts, тогда он не хочет запускаться.
Так выгляди мой app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
import {removeNgStyles,createNewHosts,createInputTransfer} from '@angularclass/hmr';
import {RouterModule, PreloadAllModules} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],

  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. А `AppComponent` - не компонент?
2. Компоненты прописаны в роутинге.
3. А чему ж тогда запускаться-то, если компонентов нет?

И вообще, берёшь ошибку из консоли, берешь имя класса и Ctrl+Shift+F по солюшену.